# Batch move all files from subdirectories to parent directory, but files have same name

Tags: shell

I have many files in sub-directories that I would like to have all moved to the parent directory.

Ex:

```
20150530XXXX/1.jpg
20150530XXXX/2.jpg
20150530XXXX/3.jpg
20150530XXXX/4.jpg
20150531XXXX/1.jpg
20150531XXXX/2.jpg
20150531XXXX/3.jpg
20150531XXXX/4.jpg
```

I found in another question on stackexchange the following commmand:

```
find ./ -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t A {} +
```

however, that seems to overwrite the image files because each have the same name (`1-4.jpg`). Is there a way I can concatenate the sub-directory's name with the file name, for instance move `20150531XXXX/4.jpg` to `./20150531XXXX_4.jpg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the `perl` version of `rename` (named `prename` on some distributions):

```
find . -type f -mindepth 2 -name '*.jpg' -exec rename -n 's!/([^/]+)$!_$1!' {} +
```

This will only show you what the command will do.  If you're happy with that, drop the `-n` option to actually rename the files (the actual rename doesn't print anything).