# Move files several directories up for several directories with similar layout

Tags: shell, shell-script, command-line, zsh, move

I have a directory with the following layout (the layout in `Directory 1` is repeated in every other `Directory <num>`):

```
Parent directory
   Directory 1
      some directory
         another directory
            <many files>
   Directory 2
       ︙
   Directory 3
   Directory 4
```

I'd like to rename the files by prefixing them with the `Directory <num>` and moving them up 3 directories so that they are under the `Parent directory` and have the original (now empty) directories deleted like:

```
Parent directory
   Directory 1_<many files>
   Directory 2
       ︙
   Directory 3
   Directory 4
```

How could I do that?

The following from a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212740/21573)

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name '*.jpg' -exec rename -n 's!/([^/]+)$!_$1!' {} +
```

renames the files to the 1st parent directory:

```
Parent directory
   Directory 1
      another directory_<many files>
   Directory 2
       ︙
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch move all files from subdirectories to parent directory, but files have same name](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212739/batch-move-all-files-from-subdirectories-to-parent-directory-but-files-have-sam)

Comment: @G-Man It is similar but I am not sure how to adjust it to my case. Question was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,
I can’t reproduce the results you claim for the command you showed. 
I got the files being renamed to `another directory_file1.jpg`,
`another directory_file2.jpg`, etc.,
***but still under the* `some directory` *directories.***

Secondly, because of the depth of your directory structure,
you should be using `-mindepth 4` instead of `2`. 
Thirdly, I strongly encourage you to use `-type f`. 
As long as you’re using `-name '*.jpg'`,
you probably won’t find any directories. 
But six to eight weeks from now,
you’ll look at this and think “I want this to apply to all my files
— I don’t need to say `-name '*.jpg'`,” and you’ll take it out. 
And then, if you don’t have `-type f`,
the `find` command might start finding directories and renaming them. 
And modifying a directory tree while you’re scanning it
is a recipe for disaster
(like the proverbial “flying the airplane while we’re still building it”).

Fourthly, the rename command to move a file up three levels
and prefix its name with `Directory <num>_` is

```
rename     -n     's!/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)$!_$1!'
        (optionally)
```

because `/[^/]+` represents a directory level,
so I just added two more copies of that.

Warning: This will, as I said, move a file up three levels. 
If you have any files deeper in the directory tree than that,
they will not be renamed to the top level;
they may be renamed to something like `Directory 3/some directory_file3.jpg`.

But it turns out that that’s easy to fix. 
To move a file to the top level *from whatever depth it is at*,
and prefix its name with `Directory <num>_`,
just use

```
s!(\./[^/]+)/.*/([^/]+)$/$1_$2/!
```

---

#### TL;DR

### So,

The final command is

```
find . -mindepth 4 -type f -exec rename -n 's!/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)$!_$1!' {} +
```

Add `-name '*.jpg'` if you want. 
Delete `-n` when the trace output shows you that it’s doing the right thing.

Beware that this has the potential to have filename collisions. 
If you have files

```
Directory 1/some directory/another directory/sunrise.jpg
```

and

```
Directory 1/some directory/another directory/mountains/sunrise.jpg
```

this command will try to rename them both to `Directory 1_sunrise.jpg`. 
Luckily the `rename` program seems to be smart/friendly enough
to do no harm in this case. 
The first such file that it sees will (probably) be renamed;
the others will be left where they are (and you will be notified). 
(You can use `-f` or `--force` to force overwriting existing files.) 
But remember that some other programs (e.g., `mv`)
have less friendly default actions.

---

For the updated question
("How can I include all directory names in the file names?"):
this is a little trickier. 
I'll explicitly assume that we are searching **`.`**,
so all the pathnames will begin with `./`. 
And I've discovered that the *perlexpr* argument to `rename`
can actually contain multiple string-modification commands. 
So we can move all files to the top level
and prefix their names with all the directory names in the path with

```
s!^\./!!;s!/!_!g
```

This also has the possibility of filename collisions.

```
Directory 1/abc/def_ghi/sunrise.jpg
```

and

```
Directory 1/abc_def/ghi/sunrise.jpg
```

will (potentially) both be renamed to `Directory 1_abc_def_ghi_sunrise.jpg`.

---

**Disclaimer:** I have tested this, but not at all thoroughly. 
I do not guarantee that this will work perfectly. 
You should make a complete backup before trying the above commands.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ran the command & got the following error `Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code).`

Comment: D'oh! I left out the `!` at the end.  Sorry.  I've fixed it; try it again now.

Comment: Thanks it works. How can I include all directory names in the file names?
By the way, this expression given to rename is a Perl expression. <strike>Could you explain or point to a short reading about how it differs from regex?</strike> I believe [this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Introduction) explains it.